# EMR streaming jobw with Ruby fails after IAM policy changes

Tags: amazon-emr

Recently amazon changed its policy for EMR jobs to define IAM roles.
I got the latest awssdk.dll and upgraded the code. I created the required policies and got my old pig jobs running successfully.

My Ruby jobs however do NOT work. I keep getting errors that the mapper file was not found, even though it is there on S3. I have verified that the mapper file is public-read to everyone and that the path is correct/exists.

any help is appreciated..Thanks

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: configuration exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.configure(PipeMapRed.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.configure(PipeMapper.java:66)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "s3://er-hadoop/Scripts/Audit/Debugging/UserId_Picker/WebPageAudit_GetDataForSpecifiedUsers_Mapper.rb": error=2, No such file or directory`

`StreamingStep stepConfig = new StreamingStep
            {
                Inputs = new List<string>
                {
                    "s3://er-upload-filestore-east/WebPageAudit/2015/04/01/*.gz",
                },
                Output = "s3://er-hadoop/Output/Mangal/testawschanges",
                Mapper = "s3://er-hadoop/Scripts/Audit/Debugging/UserId_Picker/WebPageAudit_GetDataForSpecifiedUsers_Mapper.rb",
                Reducer = "s3://er-hadoop/Scripts/Audit/Debugging/UserId_Picker/WebPageAudit_GetDataForSpecifiedUsers_Reducer.rb",
            };
            stepConfig.AddHadoopConfig("-jobconf", "mapred.output.compress=true");
             HadoopJarStepConfig config = stepConfig.ToHadoopJarStepConfig();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        const string mapper_reducer_Path = "FULL S3 Path ";
        const string mapperFileName = "YourMapper.rb";
        const string reducerFileName = "YourReducer.rb";

        string mapperFilePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", mapper_reducer_Path, mapperFileName);
        string reducerFilePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}", mapper_reducer_Path, reducerFileName);

        StreamingStep stepConfig = new StreamingStep
        {
            Inputs = new List<string>
            {
                "YOURInput",
            },
            Output = "YOUrOUTPUT",
            Mapper = mapperFileName,
            Reducer = reducerFileName,
        };

         HadoopJarStepConfig config = stepConfig.ToHadoopJarStepConfig();
         config.Args.Insert(0, "-files");
        config.Args.Insert(1, string.Format("{0},{1}", mapperFilePath, reducerFilePath));
```